# Code conventions - good or bad practice to catch exception instead of if-checking previously?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, coding-style

I want to set an `Integer` to a specific value, which is 0 or the attribute found in another class. Since instances of this class are stored in a `Map` of `List`s, but this map may be null at the point, I wonder which of the both ways to handle this are better.

```
Integer value = 0;
if (myMap != null && 
    myMap.get(keyForList) != null && 
    myMap.get(keyForList).get(0) != null) {
    value = myMap.get(keyForList).get(0).getAttribute();
}
```

Or the way which I would consider better and more efficient:

```
Integer value = 0;
try {
    value = myMap.get(keyForList).get(0).getAttribute();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // without doing anything value is 0 as expected 
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard advice is that exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control. They're relatively heavy-weight, break the standard flow of control and consequently can be difficult to follow. They should be used for *exceptional* circumstances.

That's not to say that you can't use them to recover from conditions, but if it's easy/more explicit to check for (say) `null` or zero, then you should do that in preference.

I would note (however) that Java is verbose and doesn't have simple operations for handling defaults/nulls in code such as:

```
Integer result = a.getB().getC().getD();
```

As such, my advice is:

1. check out the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), which means that you can get away with no null checks in the above scenario
2. code like the above points to a real lack of OO functionality. The code above should get object `a` itself to get `b`, and object `b` would get `c`, and so on. In it's current form it breaks the [Law of Demeter](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/lieber/LoD.html) and exposes to you how `a`, `b`, `c` etc are composed. Remember that OO is about *getting objects to do things for you*, not having them tell you what they're composed of and having you do it yourself.

Comment: Not really an expert in Java, but it seems to me that his second snippet using the exception is clearer and more readable than the first one.

Comment: +1 The standard advice is that exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid exceptions if there are no unexpected events in the code. I would suggest the following:

```
Integer value = 0;
if (myMap != null)
{ 
    if(myMap.get(keyForList) != null && !myMap.get(keyForList).isEmpty())
          value = myMap.get(keyForList).get(0).getAttribute();
    else
          System.out.println("There is no key " + keyForList + " in my map!");
}
else
    System.out.println("My map is null!");
```

This way you'll know for sure where the null value is (useful for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are much more expensive than `if`, so it's usually preferable to avoid them when possible, especially so if there's only one statement in the `try{}` block.

*However, when you can wrap lots of code inside try{}, then exceptions start making more sense. I think this is starting to be case in your example code. Even though you have just one if statement, it has complex condition. Avoiding that with `try-catch` is probably better.*

Exceptions are fine for catching errors, such as badly formed input, when it's expected that input normally is valid.

Detecting input (like method argument) null pointer by catching NullPointerException is rarely good idea. Either have `if` before, or just let the exception get thrown out of your method without intervening, if it's caller's responsiblity (it may even be sensible to detect null pointer with if and `throw NullPointerException` yourself, without calling anything else).

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are for when normal flow of execution fails, and we can't continue.
With If-else code does not break

Comment: It wouldn't break with the exception handling I use in the second snippet. I seem to not get your point?

Comment: In your case the null object check is "business" check  and this is not a typical exception handle since your code will not break. NullPointerException is typically used when to prevent break on unpredictable null objects